# Prove that $f(x) \in A$ if and only if $x \in f ^{−1} (A)$.

Tags: functions

Is there even a proof for this or is this just by definition :

$f(x) \in A$ if and only if $x \in f^{−1}(A)$.

Comment: The definition of $f^{-1}(A)$ is $\{ x | f(x) \in A \}$, so yes...

Comment: Thanks for the replies guys

Comment: @GFauxPas Perhaps you could put that in an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is the definition of $f^{-1}(A)$. From [Inverse image](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_%28mathematics%29#Inverse_image):

> Let $f$ be a function from $X$ to $Y$.  The **preimage** or **inverse image** of a set $B ⊆ Y$ under $f$ is the subset of $X$ defined by
>   $$
> f^{-1}(B) = \{ \, x \in X \, | \, f(x) \in B \}
> $$